# Does the Bockstein commute with maps induced by group homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $\sigma:G\to G$ be a homomorphism of groups.  There is an induced map in cohomology $\sigma^*:H^*(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\to H^*(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$.  We also have the Bockstein $\delta:H^n(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\to H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ which is the connecting homomorphism associated to the short exact sequence of $\mathbb{F}_p$-modules

$$0\to\mathbb{F}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{F}_p\to 0$$

> Does $\sigma^*$ commute with $\delta$?  That is, do we have $\sigma^*\circ\delta=\delta\circ\sigma^*$ as maps from $H^n(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\to H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$?

It seems like these maps should commute, but my understanding of the Bockstein is a bit clouded for me to see this clearly.

Comment: From that short exact sequence you get a long one, and sigma induces an endomorphism of that. You should check that!

Comment: Yes, and there's no need for the source and target of $\sigma$ to be the same. The Bockstein is a cohomology operation: that is, in fact it induces natural maps $H^n(X, \mathbb{F}_p) \to H^{n+1}(X, \mathbb{F}_p)$ in the cohomology of any space (natural in that they commute with maps between spaces).